# Javafx project in intellij stopped recognizing almost all imports

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

So I'm working on a project in javafx all has been going well but then this morning when I opened the project to keep working on it Intellij says id cannot resolve symbol 'what I'm trying to import'. When I run the program it still works perfectly fine but I don't want it to show me it's wrong when it's not, it's gonna make it a lot harder to debug and find problems when everything is already red and gonna make it harder when it cant suggest things as I write them. I have tried to restart the project and the computer, updated ubuntu but nothing seems to work. There was also an Intellij update when i started Intellij the first time so I don't know if that has anything to do with the problem.

Someone know how to fix this?

Here's a picture of how it looks like:
[import's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZEHU.png)

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Comment: yes I did and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to fix the problem and that is by going to File -> Invalidate Caches and that fixed the problem.